# Git - How to track a remote branch that you created from a local branch?

Tags: git

Here's the scenario.

I have a series of commits in branch my_new_branch

I want to push this branch up to the remote repo as a different name and track it.

If I do:

```
git push origin my_new_branch:different_name
```

it pushes the branch up fine.

But if I stay in my_new_branch and make another commit, if I just do

```
git push
```

it says 'Everything up to date'

Further, if I look at .git/config, I can see it hasn't set up a tracking branch.

Of course I can just do

```
git push origin my_new_branch:different_name
```

again, but how do I get it to track?

If I do

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch origin/different_name
```

it complains that the branch name already exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually looks to be the same as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, the question "[How do you make an existing git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)" indicate the possibility to set the upstream branch (the one to where you push) for a local branch (since Git1.7.0).

```
git branch --set-upstream my_new_branch origin/different_name
```

which replaces:

```
git config branch.my_new_branch.remote origin
git config branch.my_new_branch.merge refs/heads/different_name
```

By default, `git push` uses a special refspec '`:`'

> The special refspec `:` (or `+:` to allow non-fast-forward updates) directs git to push **"matching" branches**:
>   for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side.
>   This is the default operation mode if no explicit refspec is found (that is neither on the command line nor in any Push line of the corresponding remotes file).

Hence your troubles with "`git push`" (no arguments).

Comment: Hi follow up question, if i want to push my_new_branch into two separate remote branch name remote_branchA and remote_branchB
is it used this command?
`git push origin my_new_branch:remote_branchA`
`git push origin my_new_branch:remote_branchB`

Comment: @Kit: your commands should work; when pushing to *several* branch, you can no longer rely on the config for a branch, and you need to specify the remote repo and the destination refspec, which you do.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember to use -u when you push, git will set this up for you automatically.

> -u, --set-upstream
>
> For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1) and other commands. For more information, see branch..merge in git-config(1).